# Entry as tourist with intent to stay as student

Tags: visa-refusals, israel, tourist-visas, visa-free-entry

If you enter a country as a visa-waived tourist but plan to stay as a student and obtain the longer term student visa once in the country can/will the country prevent you from entering as a tourist? In other words, is it generally accepted to enter with no visa before obtaining the documents necessary to stay longer?

I ask because upon entering Israel as a US citizen I informed the border patrol officer that I planned to stay the year, and she checked that I knew that I needed to obtain a tourist visa, and then let me in as a regular tourist. This seemed weird to me, as they have no way of knowing if I will actually get the visa or if I will be accepted for it...

Comment: That's pretty standard for yeshiva students in Israel from the US

Comment: @SkinnyJ Would any other country or situation deem that acceptable though?

Comment: Some countries allow it, others don't.  If you're interested in a country other than Israel, you need to identify the country.

Comment: @phoog does the US allow it?

Comment: Close voting as "too broad" as every country has their own immigration rules.

Comment: @andrewmh20 in general, no.  In the US, nonimmigrant aliens can change from one nonimmigrant status to another, but not if they entered on the visa waiver program.  This is one of the main restrictions associated with the VWP, the other being a 90-day limit to the duration of stay.

Answer (score 2):

When I was moved to Hong Kong, they required me to "exit" the country so that I can close my "tourist visa" and enter back in on a "work visa," which allowed me to stay in the country for longer than the allotted time for a tourist.